# How to write ngrx effects and reducers so that I can have common loading flags at one place?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am working on an Angular application using @ngrx/store and @ngrx/effects.

The blogs I have been through all use flags like loading, loaded and error for a reducer. I have multiple reducers in my app and going by the current way I need to have these loading flags with each reducer.

How can I approach this problem in a way that I have all these flags available for all of my states and I don't have to write it again and again.

Please let me know if you need further details. Thank you.

Comment: You can write some kind of middleware that handles this for you

Comment: @Everest Thanks for your response. Can you refer me to some article or example code?

Comment: ...or not use middleware: https://netbasal.com/implementing-a-meta-reducer-in-ngrx-store-4379d7e1020a ¯\_(ツ)_/¯